# visualy gray out area

Tags: c#, winforms

Is there a way to lay a partly transparent panel over other elements,
to create a grayed out effect?

I tried using a panel but it ignored everything but the background color as shown in the attached "With Panel" Image.

Without panel:

[image]

With panel:

[image]

The Background Color is transparent, even thow you can't really see it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's wrong with using .Enabled = false?

Comment: You can achieve this with a 2nd form overlaying the 1st form, maybe with holes in its region..

Comment: Can you tell us for what you need grayed out effect? In winforms transparency is tricky, it's suitable for making custom shaped windows, but multiple *controls* won't be drawn on top of each other. Though your solution will work with WPF rendering engine. Another problem: if you don't disable controls they will still accept input. So what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Longoon12000 There is no visual separation with a Trackbar

Comment: To elaborate on `if you don't disable controls they will still accept input` - you can access those with keyboard, for example

Comment: check this out: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.opacity?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: add a more detail Problembeschreibung so dass wir dir besser helfen können

Comment: @Longoon12000 I didn't know it changes the Look. Do you whant to write that as an answer so i can close my question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `trackbar.Enabled = false;` instead.